# jQuery - Scrub data in all textboxes/textareas in a form?

Tags: jquery, validation, replace

My buddy at work told me that you could use jQuery to write a few lines of code that would find a single character (in this example `'\0'`) and replace it for all textboxes and textareas on the page.  Of course, he didn't tell what lines of code would do that ...

Is there a simple way to do this?  We have a problem of people copying data from an old system and the data having a `'\0'` at the end of the text.  This then gets saved in the database, and then when brought back from the database to the client, it causes an error.

**EDIT:**  I agree with Magnar's answer, but just for learning sake, does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: I added how you would go about doing it to my answer. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a job for jQuery. I would strongly recommend you remove the null-character on the server side, for added stability and security reasons.

However, this is how you would do it (slightly verbose):

```
var remove_null_character = function () {
    var field = $(this),
        old_value = field.val(),
        new_value = old_value.replace('\0', '');
    field.val(new_value);
};
$("input:text, textarea").live("blur", remove_null_character);
```

Comment: I totally agree with this btw, +1

Comment: Thanks!  That is easy, but I agree, I will keep this logic on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has string search/replace functions you can use. jQuery can fetch the specific input nodes for you, but the search/replace is just plain javascript:

```
str = str.replace('\0', '');
```

[The replace function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) also works with regular expressions by the way, in case you need something more powerful.